# How to enable AMP for custom single template with custom database

Tags: plugins

I'm using AMP (https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) to enable AMP for wordpress.
But my site using custom template for single page
My permalink structor is:

```
$newrules['([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=single&pn=$matches[1]';
```

Mean: I've created page with slug is single

Now I'm access to my website, Ex: http://example.com/abc/amp/ (default: http://example.com/abc)
But AMP not working.

How to enable AMP for custom template file?